# Connect remote MongoDB server without SSH

Tags: mongodb, remote-access, remote-server

Hi I want to connect to remote MongoDB server without using SSH tunneling(Both the client and server systems will run on windows OS). Is there any way to connect.

Comment: Actually, remote connection to MongoDB without SSH is native feature by default. Only you need to do is expose your remote MongoDB `ip:port` and connect it

Comment: @Valijon Hi. Will this work if both the systems are in different local networks.

Comment: Yes only if you can reach `host:port` from other network